# Single Channel of Mat as a matrix Opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I was trying to convert every channel of a RGB image, stored in Mat channel, into 3 2D matrices, each for R,G and B. This question maybe rudimentary, but could you please tell me how I can achieve this? Am using opencv2.4.3 in Linux, Cmake compiler.

I used split, but it stores the values again in a Mat. I want a simple 2D array, that can be accessed easily, instead of Mat. Could you please help me here?

Comment: I tried

vector<int *>channel_rgb(3)
split(src,channel_rgb)

and tried to access channel_rgb[0],[1],[2]. I think this is not working.

Comment: I don't really see how a 2D array is easier to access than a Mat...  If you don't like the .at<type> syntax why not just cast it as a Mat_ ?

Comment: and by 2D array do you mean an array of pointers to arrays?  as in double_ptr[i][j]?  If that is what you are talking about by dimensions, then internally a Mat always represents data in 1D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split`, from the [opencv docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#split):

> The functions split splits a multi-channel array into separate single-channel arrays

Comment: vector<int *>channel_rgb(3) split(src,channel_rgb). I tried this. Should I do

vector<Mat *>channel_rgb(3) split(src,channel_rgb) instead? But am looking for simple 2d array, and not Mat. Could you please help me here?

Comment: is there a easy way to conver the Mat to 2D array?

Comment: please help me, if my doubt was relevant, or waS I not clear?

Comment: Use Mat...whats the problem in using Mat?...or else copy element by element from Mat to an 2d unsigned char array...do this for all 3 channels separately...